# USB serial connection between Raspberry-pi and Android-phone

Tags: usb, serial, usb-device, linux, android

I have a Raspberry-pi-3-model-B and an Android phone device.

The connections are as follows:

1. My raspberry pi is connected to my laptop through USB (this is **not** the important part).
2. Also, from the raspberry pi's female type A USB connector - I have connected my Android phone (this is the important part and shown below):
   [image]

My Android phone's screenshot is below:-
[image]

Now on the raspberry my Android phone is listed as-
`/dev/bus/usb/001/008`

lsusb output on raspberry pi -

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2d95:6003     (<-- my Android phone)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I want to communicate **serial over USB from Raspberry Pi to my Android device**. How do I do it? For it, I think I need to have device file of the form `/dev/tty*` of the Android phone being shown on Raspberry Pi, so that I can send serial data on this `/dev/tty*` device file on Raspberry Pi. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800932/communicating-with-serial-usb-device-over-android

Comment: In the earlier days, I used to use the serial over bluetooth communication with Android devices. But it surely would require BT connectivity on the RPI side.

Comment: I'd try USB tethering. Then establish a TCP connection. Of course you need an app for this on the smartphone. It's fast and you can easyly switch to Bluetooth, WLAN or Internet. Honestly I don't know if the Android firewall allows it but that's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's about phone being the USB host for USB serial chip. This is about phone being the USB device for Raspberry Pi as the USB host.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is about electronics but how to make an Android phone to show up as a USB serial port device for a USB host.

Comment: What I said seems possible. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839321/android-connect-to-tethering-socket). Somebody already did it.

Answer (score 0):

(Before I wrote this answer I didn't think about **adb** so perhaps you simply want to use this. All you need is enable adb on the phone and run **adb shell** on the Pi.)

By default the Android phone won't show up as tty on your Pi. Because there simply is no such functionality in Android by default.

But if your phone supports USB host mode it's possible to connect various devices like pen drives or cameras. Or to make your phone act as serial device. At least some years ago only view tablets had this.

So if your phone has host mode you need to write an app which uses [this](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) library which is recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800932/communicating-with-serial-usb-device-over-android) question.

Perhaps there are other ways like Android Open Accessory (AOA) but I'd not recommend them.

I don't know your intention but I recommend to use USB tethering instead. The advantages are:

- no host mode neccessary
- fast
- no library needed, simple TCP
- you could later easily replace the USB connection by Bluetooth, Internet or WLAN, Because those support TCP too

USB tethering creates a LAN between the Pi and the phone. But you can only create a socket from the phone to the Pi because of the firewall. [Somebody already did it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839321/android-connect-to-tethering-socket).

So all you need is to write a TCP client for the phone and a server for the Pi.